# How to create an array column by repeating a value "size of another column" times?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to add a new column `score` which is an array whose length equal to the size of another column `values` and contains all values `2`.

Getting error when using `size` of the column but working fine if I replace it with a hardcoded number.

**Data**

```
columns = ["id","values"]
data = [("sample1", [12.0,10.0]), ("sample2", [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0])]
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
```

**Source DataFrame**

```
+-------+--------------------+
|     id|              values|
+-------+--------------------+
|sample1|        [12.0, 10.0]|
|sample2|[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]|
+-------+--------------------+
```

**Expected Output**

```
+-------+--------------------+--------------------+
|     id|              values|               score|
+-------+--------------------+--------------------+
|sample1|        [12.0, 10.0]|          [2, 2]    |
|sample2|[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]|        [2, 2, 2, 2]|
+-------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

**code**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df.withColumn("score",array([lit(x) for x in [2]*(size(col("values")))])).show()
```

**Getting below Error**

> : java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class
> java.util.ArrayList [2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't multiply a Python list with a Spark column. You can use the `array_repeat` function.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn('score', F.expr('array_repeat(2, size(values))'))
df2.show()
+-------+--------------------+------------+
|     id|              values|       score|
+-------+--------------------+------------+
|sample1|        [12.0, 10.0]|      [2, 2]|
|sample2|[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]|[2, 2, 2, 2]|
+-------+--------------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Function [`array_repeat`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#array_repeat) is only available for Spark 2.4+. For older versions, this can be done using UDF:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, size, lit
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, IntegerType


array_repeat_udf = udf(lambda v, n: [v for _ in range(n)], ArrayType(IntegerType()))

df1 = df.withColumn('score', array_repeat_udf(lit(2), size("values")))
df1.show()

#+-------+--------------------+------------+
#|     id|              values|       score|
#+-------+--------------------+------------+
#|sample1|        [12.0, 10.0]|      [2, 2]|
#|sample2|[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]|[2, 2, 2, 2]|
#+-------+--------------------+------------+
```